# dataclass + sqlalchemy (using mapper_registry.mapped) can't instanciate object

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-dataclasses

I really can't understand why this fails:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Column, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry


mapper_registry = registry()


@dataclass
@mapper_registry.mapped
class Token:
    __table__ = Table(
        "token",
        mapper_registry.metadata,
        Column("name", String(), primary_key=True),
        Column("symbol", String(), nullable=False),
        Column("decimals", Integer(), nullable=False),
    )

    name: str
    symbol: str
    decimals: int

Token("name", "symbol", 1)
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    Token("test", "a", 1243)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the SQLAlchemy documentation, the decorators need to be in a different order https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/dataclasses.html

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Column, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry


mapper_registry = registry()


@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class Token:
    __table__ = Table(
        "token",
        mapper_registry.metadata,
        Column("name", String(), primary_key=True),
        Column("symbol", String(), nullable=False),
        Column("decimals", Integer(), nullable=False),
    )

    name: str
    symbol: str
    decimals: int

Token("name", "symbol", 1)
```